# jQuery walkthrough plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, usability

Is there a plugin that can help create javascript app/site walkthroughs?

If not, (I can't find any via google, though I could've sworn I knew of at least one), is it a good idea (for a moderately complex app)? How does it compare to screencasts? What are some best practice if you were to do one? And in general terms, what are some ideas for how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As an example, something like [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jira-now-has-a-live-walk-through-demo-using-jquery) I just found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2009 Solutions were sparse.

2012 Solution is [Joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).

Answer (score 10):

I've created this one

[jQuery Page Walkthrough](http://jquerypagewalkthrough.github.com)

Comment: This is really cool and useful, but it still has an ugly issue documented at https://github.com/jquerypagewalkthrough/jquerypagewalkthrough.github.com/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear what are you looking for until I've seen you have mentioned screencast. thus, you may find [slideView](http://pagetalks.com/share/slideView/) useful displaying screenshots and text as a step-by-step guide.

Comment: That plugin, mixed with some fancy timeouts calling the next slide, might work about as well as a powerpoint presentation.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, though I think a screencast is superior to slides.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a plug but I've created [Overlay101](https://www.overlay101.com) that brings up an integrated walkthrough that can be managed by non developers. I think it's much easier than maintaining a jquery extension.

You can highlight elements based on id or css selectors. Once the javascript has been added to your page, you can pretty much hand it off to whomever writes the help text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I just wrote one this weekend.
check it out here:

[nbprithv.github.com/introtour-ui](http://nbprithv.github.com/introtour-ui)

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Hopscotch is a really nice framework for developers to add product tours to their pages. Currently managed by LinkedIn, and the GitHub repo is here:

[Hopscotch GitHub](https://github.com/linkedin/hopscotch)

Answer (score 0):

Plug here,

You can try [WhatFix](http://whatfix.com/), it has got easy UI based walkthrough builder, which also captures screens along with html elements. With WhatFix you can embed walkthroughs as slides, articles in [customer support pages](http://whatfix.com/#!for/customer-support-articles) as well as use javascript to invoke in-app instructions.
WhatFix has got community version which is free to use.

disclosure: I am co-founder of WhatFix.